# passing parameter to <html:link> from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

```
<html:link href="DemoAction.do?method=val1&param1=val2">DEMO</html:link>
```

How can i pass val1 and val2 from javascript ?

Answer (score 2):

Add **`styleId="myLink"`** to the `<html:link>` in order to query the element with JavaScript.
Then you can do the following in JS:

```
var val1 = "newval1", val2 = "newval2";

// Option 1: Set the href attribute regardless of its current value
var link = document.getElementById("myLink");
link.setAttribute("href", "DemoAction.do?method="+val1+"&param1="+val2);

// Option 2: Set the href attribute depending on its current value
var link = document.getElementById("myLink"),
    hrefParts = link.getAttribute("href").split("?");
link.setAttribute("href", hrefParts[0]+"?method="+val1+"&param1="+val2);
```